# Как разрабатывать сайт в команде? (совместное редактирование)

Tags: html

Только учимся. Как сделать, чтоб редактировать страницы и не мешать друг другу?
Я пишу скрипты, друг пишет html
Мне нужно немного этот html изменить. 
Как сделать, чтоб мои изменения отобразились у него?
Какими инструментами пользоваться?

Comment: Технология Git...

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev, или одна из кучи других систем

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Регистрируетесь в github, создаете репозиторий, каждый разветвляется в свою ветку и делает изменения, потом применяете изменения в основную ветку, обновляетесь ит.д.
Описать простым языком давольно тяжело, гугли git

Советую посмотреть уроки от htmlacademy, там хорошо описан принцип и процесс работы